# 3D nonogram – What's in the box?

Tags: visual, grid-deduction, three-dimensional, nonogram

This is a **three-dimensional nonogram**. The first six squares depict the layers of a $6\times6\times6$ cube. The final square gives the enumerations for the Z-axis, top to bottom. Some rules:

- The grid has three different colours: Red, blue and orange. The black numbers can refer to stretches of any colour, whereas coloured numbers are always the same colour of the squares they refer to. Cells filled with different colours do not need to have a gap between them (that is, "1 1" can refer to one red cell and one blue cell which are adjacent to one another).
- If a row or column has no numbers, that means that the composition of that row/column is **unknown**. Note that this is different than the usual practice in nonograms where a missing number means that the row/column has no coloured cells at all. In our case, such rows can be explicitly marked with a zero.
- The Z-axis enumerations are all single digits, so e.g. 11 means two stretches of one, not one stretch of eleven. Similarly, "5x1" means five stretches of one.

> [image]

What's in the box?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Step 1: Solving the nonogram:

> [image: 1]

Step 2: Transcription to Blender:

> [image: 2]
>   <sub>Tool used: Blender 2.8</sub>

Step 3: Interpretation:

> Clearly it's a box containing individual digits.

Step 4: Separation:

> [image: 4]

Comment: nice one @John +1